# CUDA -prec-sqrt=false VS2010

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, cuda

I am trying to set -prec-sqrt=false for my code in VS2010.
The only place that I could see was on the myfile.cu's property pages(CUDA C/C++ => Host => Additional Compiler Options) but when I put it there it reports an unkown compiler option and ignores. In the very same page there is a toggle for "use fast math" for example.
Where do I set cuda compiler options and is there a specific way (as opposed to just -prec-sqrt=false).
Thanks in advance.

Comment: In *Nvidia Nsight Eclipse Edition*, there is such toggle button under *project* -> *Properties* -> *Build* -> *Settings* -> *Tool Settings* -> *Optimization*. In VS, this option seems to be unavailable to be selected as a toggle but you can add it in the *project properties* -> *CUDA C/C++* -> *Command Line* -> *Additional Options* as `-prec-sqrt false`. You should drop `=` in your command.

Comment: @Farzad if you want to provide that as an answer, I would upvote.

Comment: @RobertCrovella thanks. I posted it as an answer.

Comment: Yes @Farzad, that was useful, thanks. Here comes your vote :-). Well I spoke too soon, I don't have the "reputation" for an upvote apparently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In *Nvidia Nsight Eclipse Edition*, there is such toggle button under *Project* -> *Properties* -> *Build* -> *Settings* -> *Tool Settings* -> *Optimization*. In VS, this option seems to be unavailable to be selected as a toggle but you can add it in the *project properties* -> *CUDA C/C++* -> *Command Line* -> *Additional Options* as `-prec-sqrt false`. You should drop `=` in your command.